# zsh bindkey with history

Tags: shell, command-line, zsh

In short I'd like to map `Ctrl + 2` to the second most recently logged command in my .zsh_history file. Normally I would type `!-2` to achieve this. However, to recreate this behavior in a shell function I wrote the following:

```
function two_back {
  HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history
  command=$(history | tail -n 2 | head -n 1 | cut -c 8-)

  echo -n "$command"
}
```

This outputs the value that I would expect, so it seems fine to me. In fact, If I just run the function `two_back` and press `<Enter>` it works as expected. The issue seems to reveal itself after I bind the function to some keystrokes.

First I convert the function into a zsh widget, so that I can bind it to some keystrokes...

```
$ zle -N two_back_widget two_back
```

Then I use the `bindkey` command to create the mapping...

```
$ bindkey '^@' two_back_widget
```

Now when I type `Ctrl + 2` my z-shell line editor `zle` contains the output that I expect. But when I attempt to run the command by pressing `<Enter>` nothing happens... Can anyone else reproduce this? And does anyone know why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is not working is, that while the command was printed to the terminal (*output*) it was not written in the terminal (*input*).

In order to actually enter the command like it has been typed into the shell this should work:

```
function two_back {
   HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history
   command=$(history | tail -n 2 | head -n 1 | cut -c 8-)

   BUFFER="$command"
   CURSOR=$#BUFFER
}

zle -N two_back_widget two_back
bindkey '^@' two_back_widget
```

#### Explanation:

- Within *zle widgets* `BUFFER` contains the current command line. It can also be modified. In this case `BUFFER` is set to the value of `command`. Writing to `BUFFER` effectively edits the current command on the command line.
- `CURSOR` contains the cursor position on the command line. By setting it to the lengt of `BUFFER` the cursor will be placed at the end of the input. This is not strictly necessary, without setting it the cursor will remain in the same place. If the command line was previously empty the cursor will be on the very left of the command.